# Android webview bad rendering

Tags: android, webview, ionic-framework

I'm creating a application with [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) framework and wrapping it into android app (webview), everything seems to work fine except that when I put it on my device rendering is broken.

[image: Example]

Source:

```
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

```
<ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>



    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <tour-form>
            <form id="submit">
                <div class="list">
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="TID" name="tc">
                    </label>
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Code" name="code">
                    </label>
                    <button class="button button-light">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </tour-form>
        <content id="content"></content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

Anybody knows a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1880

It has something to do with the interpretation of the .scroll-content: margin-top: -1px; on some devices, which is part of the ionic.css file.

Try to set this in your style.css:
`.scroll-content {padding-top:1px;}`

This solution works on my device (Samsung Galaxy S2, Android 4.2.2)